# Wpf C# Como puedo convertir una imagen a BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf

Quiero realizar una rotacion de imagen en memoria (se supone que ya lo tengo cargado)

```
private void btnRotacion90_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var bi =  ImgFotoUsuario.Source as BitmapImage;
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.Rotation = Rotation.Rotate90;
            bi.EndInit();
            ImgFotoUsuario.Source = bi;
        }
```

Sin embargo he tratado de hacerlo de diferente formas incluyendo las siguientes lineas de codigo

```
bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
```

Ademas de tratar de convertir la imagen a otro tipo (como stream o bytes ) para asi despues nuevamente convertirlo en ImgMapImage pero aun no se como hacerlo

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Funciona el código para rotar la imagen? Que pasa cuando añades las opciones de cache y para que lo haces? Para que quieres convertir la imagen a otro formato? Te recomiendo que pulses en [edit] y expliques de una mejor manera tu problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pides es muy sencillo, y estás muy cerca de la respuesta de hecho, el `BitmapImage` es mejor pasarlo a `ImageBrush` para mostrarlo en pantalla, pero te haré el ejemplo completo, acá voy a cargar una foto y la pondré como fondo en un `Rectangle` llamando **rt_foto**:

Para cargar la imagen:

```
private void CargarButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog _dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    string filtro = "Archivo  (*.png)|*.png";
    _dialog.Filter = filtro;
    _dialog.Multiselect = false;
    if (_dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        rt_foto.Fill = ToImageBrush(_dialog.FileName);
    }
}
```

Vas a necesitar este metodo:

```
/// <summary>
/// Convierte una ruta en disco a ImageBrush
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path">Ruta del archivo</param>
/// <returns>ImageBrush</returns>
public static ImageBrush ToImageBrush(this string path)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Image image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(path);
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
    image.Source = (ImageSource)bitmapImage;
    return new ImageBrush()
    {
        ImageSource = (ImageSource)bitmapImage
    };
}
```

Puedes usarlo de forma no estática sacando el `static` y el `this` del nombre del método.
Y finalmente para rotar la imagen que estás usando:

```
private void RotarButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RotateTransform aRotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
    aRotateTransform.CenterX = 0.5;
    aRotateTransform.CenterY = 0.5;
    aRotateTransform.Angle = 90;

    rt_foto.Fill.RelativeTransform = aRotateTransform;

}
```

Opcionalmente puedes refactorizar el último método para que te sirva para rotar otras imágenes y no solo la del `Rectangle` o también en vez de ponerle que rote 90 grados lo puedes pasar por parámetro para que rote en otros ángulos, quedaría algo así:

```
private void RotarButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Rotar(rt_foto, 90);

}

private void Rotar(Rectangle rect, double angle)
{
    RotateTransform aRotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
    aRotateTransform.CenterX = 0.5;
    aRotateTransform.CenterY = 0.5;
    aRotateTransform.Angle = angle;

    rect.Fill.RelativeTransform = aRotateTransform;

}
```

Espero te sirva, yo no uso nunca el control `Image` porque es muy problemático, prefiero el `Rectangle`.. pero eso ya es cosa de cada cual.

Un saludo.

---

Agrego:

Para usar esto en Image en vez de Rectangle, el control se llamará img_foto

Para cargar la foto:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog _dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    string filtro = "Archivo  (*.png)|*.png";
    _dialog.Filter = filtro;
    _dialog.Multiselect = false;
    if (_dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        img_foto.Source = ToImageSource(_dialog.FileName);
    }
}

public System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage ToImageSource(string path)
{
    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage _bitmap = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
    _bitmap.BeginInit();
    _bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(path);
    _bitmap.EndInit();
    return _bitmap;
}
```

Y para rotarlo haz este método y le envias el control por parámetro:

```
private void RotarImagen(Image control, Rotation value)
{
    var biOriginal = (BitmapImage)control.Source;

    var biRotated = new BitmapImage();
    biRotated.BeginInit();
    biRotated.UriSource = biOriginal.UriSource;
    biRotated.Rotation = value;
    biRotated.EndInit();

    control.Source = biRotated;
}
```

Espero que ahora te sirva..
Bye!

Comment: ¿Es mejor utilizar un Rectangle para cualquier tipo de edicion de fotos?, porque lo que pasa es que al menos tengo que hacer la rotacion y recorte en mi proyecto en la version 1.0 y ya tengo el recorte utilizando el image y no quiero avanzar mas, si mas adelante se me va a complicar demasiado

Comment: En MI experiencia si.. pero conseguí agregar los métodos para usar el control Image en vez de Rectangle, espero que te sirvan, ya que igual me ayudó a aprender a hacerlo ahora que lo preuntaste, bye